# Tkinter GUI Creating New Widgets?

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter, widget

I'm new to Tkinter but I'm using it to create a football management game [that looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usI3x.png).

My code functions as expected however, I'm worried about its efficiency.
In my game, I use the button widget to navigate through menus, each menu I create using a function. I use code that looked something like this:

```
frame = tk.Frame(root, #insert code)

transfersMenuButton = tk.Button(frame, command=TransfersMenu, #insert code)
button.place(frame, #insert code)

def TransfersMenu():
  clear()
  label = tk.Label(frame, #insert code)
  label.place(frame, #insert code)      
  #more code

def clear():
  frame.destroy()
  frame = tk.Frame(root, #insert code)
```

As you may see, the clear command destroys the frame and recreates it. This is to clear all widgets on the frame and prepare for a new menu to be opened with new widgets. Will destroying and recreating widgets like lead to a memory leak due to new frames being created? I'm not sure how to rewrite all of my code so that I reuse all my widgets rather than destroying them so - if so - how could I go about doing so?
(Sorry, if I haven't communicated the issue well)

Answer (score 1):

This this one out of many approaches that you can try, check the example below

```py
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

def switch(frame):
    clear()
    frame.pack()

def clear():
    for f in frames:
        f.pack_forget()

frame1=Frame(root)
#widgets of frame1
label1=Label(frame1,text='Label 1')
label1.pack()

frame2=Frame(root)
#widgets of frame2
label2=Label(frame2,text='Label 2')
label2.pack()

frame1_button=Button(root,text='Frame 1',command=lambda:switch(frame1))
frame1_button.pack()
frame2_button=Button(root,text='Frame 2',command=lambda:switch(frame2))
frame2_button.pack()

frame1.pack() #initial frame

frames=[frame1,frame2] #store the frames in a list

root.mainloop()
```

**NOTES**

- The `clear` function here iterates through the list of all frames and temporarily removes them (technically only the one that is currently packed, since the rest aren't to begin with) using the `pack_forget()` method, it can be used with any geometry manager in a similar manner.
- The `switch` function takes in the frame required to be packed as the parameter, calls the `clear` function followed by using `pack()` method on the frame.

Comment: One thing is I define all my widgets within functions (such as transfersMenu() ) and these functions can be run an unlimited time (as seen above) due to my game being a football management game with a menu. How could I change this?

Comment: @Xaeol Its not very clear what you want but from what I've understood, you want a different set of widgets to appear each time a new option from the menu is selected, but your current approach is to destroy the frame and place the widgets every time the function is called (correct me if I got it wrong) what I am suggesting is to have these widgets *pre-placed* in the frame (you can place other widgets later as well) and all your function needs to do is to call `clear` whereby forgetting the currently open frame and placing the frame you desire.